# Passing Image and Username to servlet

Tags: servlets

I am passing an fileUpload and name of the user to the servlet.I am able to upload a file but not the username as i am fetching the value of the user by requst.getparemeter("userName") but it is giving me null value.I Checked everything but not able to unserstand what exactly the problem..

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>AJAX jquery file Upload in Java Web Application</title>
    <script src="js/Jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ajaxfileupload.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript">
    function validateName(){
        var empName=document.getElementById("userName").value;
        alert(empName);
    }

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
    .centered{
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="UploadFile"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <div class="centered">

    <h2 style="text-align:center;">Using AJAX, jquery and Servlet to upload File in Java Web Application</h2>
     <input id="userName" name="userName" type="text" placeholder="minutes"/>
    <input type="file" name="file" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="validateName()"/>
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>


    package com;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

    public class UploadFile extends HttpServlet {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                public UploadFile()
                {
                }


                protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                    System.out.println(  "Save Path in Database:");  

                              boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);




                        if (isMultipart) {

                            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
                            String empName=request.getParameter("userName");
                            System.out.print("here the name of the file is "+empName);
                            try{

                                        List  items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                                                                Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
                                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                                    FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();
                                     empName=request.getParameter("empName");
                                    if (!item.isFormField()) {
                                        String fileName = item.getName();
                                       System.out.print("here the name of the file is "+fileName);
                                       String fileSplit[]=fileName.split("\\.");
                                       System.out.println("the length of the file"+fileSplit.length);

                                           String fileDatabasePath=empName+"."+fileSplit[1];
                                           System.out.println("Name of the file is "+fileDatabasePath);



                                        String fileBase = getServletContext().getInitParameter("IMAGE_FILEBASE");
                                        File filePath  = new File(fileBase  + File.separator);

                                        File uploadedFile = new File(filePath + "/" + fileName);
                                        item.write(uploadedFile);
                                     // Save the below path in database
                                        String url = getServletContext().getInitParameter("imgsd") + fileName ;
                                        String url1="E:/Suraj/AjaxServletFileUpload/WebContent/images/"+fileDatabasePath;
                                       System.out.println(  "Save Path in Database: "+url1);
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (FileUploadException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                }

    } 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UploadFile</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.UploadFile</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadFile</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UploadFile</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>IMAGE_FILEBASE</param-name>
    <param-value>E:/Suraj/AjaxServletFileUpload/WebContent/images/ </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>imgsd</param-name>
    <param-value>http://localhost:8080/AjaxServletFileUpload/</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

I am not able to get any error in console.I am a null value in my console.  I am passing an fileUpload and name of the user to the servlet.I am able to upload a file but not the username as i am fetching the value of the user by requst.getparemeter("userName") but it is giving me null value .

Answer (score 0):

You are using  Apache Commons File Upload for the file but still trying to use request.getParameter for the username.  You can't do that.  If your form is "multipart/form-data" then you have to use Apache Commons File Upload for all the parameters in the form since  request.getParameter will not work.